# Ruby on rails get id from instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance

I have an instance variable `@user` 
so in HTML `<%=link_to @user %>` gives me the result:

```
{"id"=>2, "restaurant"=>"sea food", "password"=>"123", "name"=>"a", "email"=>"a", "telephone"=>"123", "created_at"=>"2016-10-09T04:00:24.010Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-10-09T04:00:24.010Z"}
```

I want to get the value of id, but when I write:`<%=link_to @user[:id] %>` it returns me the result :`/restaurant/home`, which is the route of my home function inside my restaurant controller and I can't understand why.

This is my controller:

```
class RestaurantController < ApplicationController


def home
    @user = session['loginedUser']
  end



def login

  end

  def checkLogin
    @user = User.find_by_restaurant(params[:user][:restaurant])
    if @user != nil && @user[:password] == params[:user][:password]
        session['loginedUser'] = @user
        redirect_to :controller=>'restaurant',:action=>'home'
    else
        session['loginedUser'] = nil
    #   redirect_to :controller=>'restaurant',:action=>'login'
    end
  end

  def logout
    session['loginedUser'] = nil
    redirect_to :controller=>'restaurant',:action=>'home'
  end
end
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not save complex objects within your session object. Session data is saved within a cookie by default and many browsers accept only cookies until 4kB. Other issues exists too.

I suggest this change:

```
def checkLogin
   ...
   session['loginedUser'] = @user.id
   ...     
end

def home
  @user = User.find session['loginedUser']
end
```

Your link to should look like this

`<%=link_to id: @user.id %>`. This solution is not realy Rails like. There should be an appropriate helper. You can check your routes with `rake routes | grep home`. You will see something like `xxx_xxx_home_xxx_restaurant /restaurant/home(.format) restaurant#home`. The first part is the helper name and you can add `_path` or `_url`. This may look like `<%=link_to xxx_xxx_home_xxx_restaurant_path id: @user.id %>`

Comment: thanks but I got undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x007fc80419f900> when i tried <%=link_to id: @user.id %> but actually just modify session['loginedUser'] = @user.id  and <%=link_to @user %> is working, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you have to change your code like suggested above. If you still save your user object within the `session` you need to use `id: @user[:id]`